# I want to import a class from a .py to another .py but it says : no module named "example"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My folders looks like this:

```
Code_Sources (folder)
    main.py
    Class (folder)
        game_class.py
        player_class.py
```

I made in game_class.py:

```
from player_class import *
```

And when I run the game_class.py I have no problem.
But when I run main.py which contains:

```
import pygame

from Class.game_class import Game

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    pygame.init()
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

It says that an error comes from game_class.py and `No module named 'player_class'`.
I don't understand why.

I tried the method of `init.py` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly did you try with `init.py`?

Comment: i try to put in my Class forlder __ init__.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out python documentation on [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Also it's good practise to follow style guide for python code [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), especially the [package and module names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) section.

Let's rebuild your code structure a bit.

```
code_sources
  | __init__.py
  | main.py
  | classes
      | __init__.py
      | game_class.py
      | player_class.py
```

The names of directories are still vague imo, think about giving them name that reflect what they are grouping inside.

All your internal imports should look like this now:

```py
from code_sources.classes import player_class
```

Even when you are importing something between `game_class` and `player_class`

Also try to avoid asking questions that already has been answered or are well documented by the software creators. Python is perfect example of great documentation.

Here is one example of your question in StackOverflow: [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)